# cmd - Invalid number. Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Here is my code. I don't know, how to make it with decimal numbers. I found there 1 tip to write it for example like that: 3/10 (=0.3). But I have much more numbers and it throw me every time error type:

> "Invalid number. Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision."

Does someone know how to fix it?
Thank you

```
@echo off
title Converter
color 0b
goto start

:start
cls
echo Converter 1.0
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
goto menu

:menu
cls
color 0a
echo What to convert?
echo 1) Kcal to Kg
set /p menu=
if %menu%==1 goto kcaltokg
goto unknownsymbol

:unknownsymbol
cls
color 0c
echo Unknown symbol!
goto menu

:kcaltokg
cls
echo Set amount of Kcal:
set /p kcal=
set /a "kcal=%kcal%*1428571428571/10000000000000000"
echo %kcal% kg
pause
```

Comment: This is one of only two times I will recommend using PowerShell instead of batch. As the error states, batch can only handle 32-bit integers.

Comment: Windows command interpreter supports only 32-bit signed integer arithmetic. Floating point or 64-bit integer arithmetic is not supported by `cmd.exe`. Best would be to use a different scripting language like VBScript, JScript, or PowerShell for this task. Or this converter is written in C++/C# compiled to a nice and easy to use GUI application. Or a spreadsheet application like Excel is used for this converter. BTW: There are lots of free unit converters, search with a www search engine for `convert units free Windows or Microsoft`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this produce the correct math? Note that the `kcal` variable is a text string and not a number. You cannot do any math with it. Also, I do not know that this retains any of the color changes.

```
@echo off
title Converter
color 0b
goto start

:start
cls
echo Converter 1.0
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
goto menu

:menu
cls
color 0a
echo What to convert?
echo 1) Kcal to Kg
set /p menu=
if %menu%==1 goto kcaltokg
goto unknownsymbol

:unknownsymbol
cls
color 0c
echo Unknown symbol!
goto menu

:kcaltokg
cls
echo Set amount of Kcal:
set /p kcal=

FOR /F "usebackq" %%n IN (`powershell -NoProfile -Command %kcal%*1428571428571/10000000000000000`) DO (SET "kcal=%%n")

echo %kcal% kg
pause
```